# how do I fix this error, "There is no arguments given that corresponds to the required formal parameter"?

Tags: c#, if-statement, methods, calculation

I was to call a method within an else if to use for if users age is < 21 or|| >75 output message box. this error is coming up when i try to call the method

this is my code

```
 public int GetAge(string DOB, DateTime startDate)
    {
        int driverAge = startDate.Year - DateTime.Parse(DOB).Year;

        if (startDate.Month < DateTime.Parse(DOB).Month || (startDate.Month == DateTime.Parse(DOB).Month && startDate.Day < DateTime.Parse(DOB).Day))
        {
            driverAge--;

        }
            return driverAge;

    }
```

...

```
else if (GetAge())
        {

        }
```

Comment: `GetAge` expects two parameters.  You are not passing any.  It also returns an integer, not a boolean.

Comment: how do i fix this? @Amy

Comment: Pass some parameters?  It expects a date of birth and a start date.  So provide them.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You don't need to have startDate in the arguments. You can declare it inside the function
and give a string that can be parsed as a Date as a parameter

```
    public int GetAge(string DOB)
        {
            DateTime startDate = new Date();
            int driverAge = startDate.Year - DateTime.Parse(DOB).Year;

            if (startDate.Month < DateTime.Parse(DOB).Month || (startDate.Month == DateTime.Parse(DOB).Month && startDate.Day < DateTime.Parse(DOB).Day))
            {
                driverAge--;

            }
                return driverAge;

        }
```

and Call it like this

```
GetAge("You date string comes here")<21 || GetAge("You date string comes here") > 75
```

Comment: thank you so much, I used this and was able to get it working!

Answer (score 3):

You have declared a method that has two parameters of type string and DateTime:

```
public int GetAge(string DOB, DateTime startDate)
{
    int driverAge = startDate.Year - DateTime.Parse(DOB).Year;

    if (startDate.Month < DateTime.Parse(DOB).Month
        || (startDate.Month == DateTime.Parse(DOB).Month
            && startDate.Day < DateTime.Parse(DOB).Day))
    {
        driverAge--;
    }
    return driverAge;
}
```

But are calling it without any arguments:

```
else if (GetAge())
{

}
```

Also the return type of GetAge is an integer, but an if statement only evaluates boolean expressions.

You want something like the following:

```
int age = GetAge('08/18/1990', DateTime.Now);
if (age < 21)
{
    /* Do something. */
}
else if (age > 75)
{
    /* Do something. */
}
```

Answer (score 0):

You should pass 2 params when you call the function

```
if (GetAge("27/12/2019",new DateTime(2010, 8, 18)) < 21 || GetAge("27/12/2019",new DateTime(2010, 8, 18)) > 75)
    {

    }
```

Comment: the date must always be today's date for the calculation and the date the user enters. i can use specific dates like that i dont think.

Comment: @kitty Important details like that should be part of your question.  It'll save time in the back-and-forth if all the requirements are up-front.  That said, this answers the question that was asked.

Comment: today's date is DateTime.Now and user input is the first argument

Comment: is there no way i can just call the driverAge result to calculate?